# Change label color over a specific value in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, css, graph, chart.js

I have a Chart.js like this:
[image]

I want change color of horizontal label over 70.00 - 73.99.
There is a specif option to do this?
Tks

Comment: I don'y think it is possible yet, check [this](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2442)

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet possible. You would need something similar to https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/6037 to be implemented. You could ask @kurkle in the [Slack channel](https://chartjs-slack.herokuapp.com/) if he has plans to resume that PR